# Error Veins shared libs

Tags: makefile, omnet++, veins

I decided to create a new OMNeT++ project to keep my applications separated from the Veins project.

However, I am facing problems when I try to execute the appls from my project src folder.

I've already configured my project and Veins according to the following link:
https://omnetpp.org/pmwiki/index.php?n=Main.HowToExtendAProject

I also tried to recreate the makefiles from my project but it doesnt work.

My .cc files use Register_Class() and Define_Module() properly but the Error Log keeps showing this error  **Class not found -- perhaps its code was not linked in, or the class wasn't registered with Register_Class(), or in the case of modules and channels, with Define_Module()/Define_Channel() -- in module (omnetpp::cModule)**

I really feel the problem has to do with the makefiles because when I import this application from my project to Veins src folder it works perfectly.

Ps.: I'm using OMNeT 5.1 + Veins 4.5 + Sumo 0.28

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the command line arguments you use to run your simulations? If you use the IDE to run your simulations, look for console output starting with the name of the binary (either `opp_run` or the name of the binary you compiled)

Comment: $ opp_run -m -u Tkenv -n .:../../src:../../../../../veins-master/examples/veins:../../../../../veins-master/src/veins --image-path=../../../../../veins-master/images -l ../../../../../veins-master/out/gcc-debug/src/veins test.ini

Comment: Just to emphasize: I'm using veins dynamic library to run the applications in my applications src folder.

Comment: Indeed, the only library you seem to ask OMNeT++ to load when running your simulation (specified with the `-l` switch) is that of Veins. Try adding another `-l yourModelLibrary` switch and you should see your models being found. To have OMNeT++ output a quick overview of which models are registered in all of the model libraries you load, you can add `-h classes` to your `opp_run` invocation.

Comment: I really found it hard to extend veins project. Thus, I added my applications to the veins applications folders. But I keep asking myself if there is a simple way to extend veins in a new project using all the necessary includes. I already followed a tutorial on OMNET webpage (https://omnetpp.org/pmwiki/index.php?n=Main.HowToExtendAProject) but it's still unsucessfull. It can't find the includes.